# How to install libxslt on windows7?

Tags: python, lxml, libxslt

When I want to install lxml,it says:

> make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed

So I have installed `libxml2` and has download `libxslt`. But I don't know how to install it. I can't show the image.

These are files in the document:

> acconfig.h  aclocal.m4  AUTHORS  ChangeLog  config.guess  config.h.in 
>   config.sub   configure  configure.in  COPYING   Copyright depcomp doc
>   examples  FEATURES  INSTALL  install-sh  libexslt  libexslt.pc.in 
>   libxslt  libxslt.m4  libxslt.pc.in  libxslt.spec  libxslt.spec.in 
>   ltmain.sh  Makefile.am  Makefile.in  missing  NEWS  python  README 
>   tests TODO  vms  win32  xslt-config.inxsltConf.sh.in  xsltproc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention development packages have a suffix, so normally I would try to search for installer for something like `libxslt-dev` or `libxslt-devel`.

But for the Windows case, as it is written on [XSLT C library website](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/downloads.html) Igor Zlatkovic is now the maintainer of the Windows port. Try to install his binaries. I remember doing it about a year ago. I was doing xml and xslt manipulation both from C++ and Python then, and it worked for me.

http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html

Comment: He's on Windows. There's no `-dev` or `-devel` packages per-se. Maybe there's a pre-compiled copy somewhere?

Comment: There's no clear place to place these. They are just *.zip archives.

Answer (score -1):

[PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.2.4) has pre-built Windows binaries as does [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml). Both of these pre-built binary sources have precompiled versions of the `libxml2` and `libxslt` that will be installed correctly in your Python installation.

Note that if you use [`easy_install`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html), it should just do the right thing.

Comment: `easy_install` does not do the right thing. It throws errors trying to find `libxslt`